# @Provides with @Named doesn't work for supertype declared variables

Tags: java, guice

I'm currently exploring Guice capabilities and faced a strange behaviour - when I declare variable as

```
@Inject
@Named("dragon")
Dragon dragon2;
```

injection works as expected, but when I want to declare dragon2 as interface (it implements Creature), i. e.

```
@Inject
@Named("dragon")
Creature dragon2;
```

I get an error

No implementation for warlock.rincewind.creatures.Creature annotated with `@com.google.inject.name.Named(value=dragon)` was bound.

Here's my provider method:

```
@Named("dragon")
@Provides
public Dragon providesDragon() {
    Dragon d = new Dragon("Morkeleb");
    return d;
}
```

I know, there are lots of different ways to overcome this (the simplest one is change provides return type to Creature) but I'm trying to get the reason for such limitation.

Comment: In Guice, `Key`s are not covariant.  So it is totally acceptable to have `@Named("dragon") Creature` and `@Named("dragon") Dragon` bound to different implementations or instances.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider, for example:

```
interface Creature { }

class Dragon implements Creature { }
class Dog implements Creature { }

public class Kennel {
    @Inject @Named("foo") Creature c;
}

public class KennelModule extends Abstract Module {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Dragon.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("foo"));
        bind(Dog.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("foo"));
    }
}
```

How would your injection know whether to bind `Dragon` or `Dog` here?

It can't! **Injection keys are not covariant**. What you need to do instead is, **specify the subclass that you want to inject, and bind it to the interface or superclass that you are injecting to.** In other words:

```
public class KennelModule extends Abstract Module {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Creature.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("foo").to(Dragon.class);
    }
}
```

This will give you the behavior you want. You can also still bind injections for `Dragon` specifically, of course.